# Add a top bar to a bottom navigation view item

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I want to put a bar in the top of each Bottom Navigation View Item's items when it is selected. As the image below, but i don't find the way to do it.[image]

I dont have any idea how to do it

Comment: you can create a selector and add the line in yoour selected drawable

Comment: You have to create custom drawable and use tab indicator as a bacground

Comment: A not-so-correct answer: what you want to achieve looks like an upside-down TabLayout. Place the TabLayout at the bottom of your screen with this attribute `app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"`.

Answer (score 4):

**You can achieve it by adding a view on the bottom navigation, check the code below, you can also use this to add any view on the bottom navigation item, such as Badge, small icon, etc..**

**Layout** xml for the bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

**Controller (show/hide)**

```
class BottomNavigationHelper {

    fun showBadge(context: Context, bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView, @IdRes itemId: Int) {
        removeBadge(bottomNavigationView, itemId)
        val itemView = bottomNavigationView.findViewById<BottomNavigationItemView>(itemId)
        val badge = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_red_badge, bottomNavigationView, false)
        itemView.addView(badge)
    }

    fun removeBadge(bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView, @IdRes itemId: Int) {
        val itemView = bottomNavigationView.findViewById<BottomNavigationItemView>(itemId)
        if (itemView.childCount == 3) {
            itemView.removeViewAt(2)
        }
    }
}
```

**sample call**

```
BottomNavigationHelper().showBadge(mContext, bottomNavigationView, R.id.navigation_home)
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix issue with removing badge with Farouq Afghani's answer.

```
class BottomNavigationHelper {

companion object {
    var previousItemId: Int = 0
}

fun showBadge(
    context: Context,
    bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView,
    @IdRes itemId: Int
) {
    if (previousItemId != 0) {
        removeBadge(bottomNavigationView, previousItemId)
    }
    previousItemId = itemId
    val itemView = bottomNavigationView.findViewById<BottomNavigationItemView>(itemId)
    val badge = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.layout_nav_top_line, bottomNavigationView, false)
    itemView.addView(badge)
}

fun removeBadge(bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView, @IdRes itemId: Int) {
    val itemView = bottomNavigationView.findViewById<BottomNavigationItemView>(itemId)
    if (itemView.childCount == 3) {
        itemView.removeViewAt(2)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Payam Kokabi, you could use a `selector` to determine the background drawable to show. Something along the following lines should work,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_item_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_item" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

P.S - You can set the selector as the item background using,

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_item_selector"
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on  "@drawable/bottom_item_selected", please. In my bottom navigation bar items will be in grey color when not selected and orange when selected and i also need that extra stroke on top like Amanda asked in question.