# java.lang.ClassCastException: BottomNavigationView cannot be cast to BottomNavigationItemView

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, exception, classcastexception

I was working on adding a top bar to my bottom navigation view selected item, I followed this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161055/add-a-top-bar-to-a-bottom-navigation-view-item). But I got hit with a cast exception and the app crash. How to fetch the BottomNavigationItemView and add view to it so that I can display the top bar.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.abc.project, PID: 26285
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.project/com.abc.project.views.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3482)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3634)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2094)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7815)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:593)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1094)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView
        at com.abc.project.views.BottomNavigationHelper.showBadge(HomeActivity.kt:128)
        at com.abc.project.views.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:77)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8004)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7988)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3455)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3634) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2094) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7815) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:593) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1094)
```

onCreate of the activity

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        databinding=DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_home)

        viewmodel=ViewModelProvider(this,factory).get(HomeViewmodel::class.java)

        BottomNavigationHelper().showBadge(this, databinding.bottomNavView, R.id.bottom_nav_view)
    }
```

HelperClass for interacting with BottomNavigationView

```
class BottomNavigationHelper {

    fun showBadge(context: Context, bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView, @IdRes itemId: Int) {
        removeBadge(bottomNavigationView, itemId)
        val itemView = bottomNavigationView.findViewById<BottomNavigationItemView>(itemId)
        val badge = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_bottom_nav_badge, bottomNavigationView, false)
        itemView.addView(badge)
    }

    fun removeBadge(bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView, @IdRes itemId: Int) {
        val itemView = bottomNavigationView.findViewById<BottomNavigationItemView>(itemId)
        if (itemView.childCount == 4) {
            itemView.removeViewAt(2)
        }
    }
}
```

xml code for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="data"
            type="com.abc.project.viewmodels.HomeViewmodel" />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cream"
        tools:context=".views.HomeActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemBackground="@color/cream"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:paddingVertical="4sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Stuck with this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: post your xml also

Comment: It must mean that the `bottom_nav_view` in your xml is defined as a `BottomNavigationView`, and not a `BottomNavigationItemView`

Comment: @Ivo understood, but how to fetch the BottomNavigationView and add view to it so that I can display the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you're casting to `BottomNavigationItemView`:

```
fun showBadge(
    context: Context,
    bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView,
    @IdRes itemId: Int) {
    ...
    val itemView = bottomNavigationView.findViewById<BottomNavigationItemView>(itemId)
```

By providing that type in the `findViewById` call, you're specifying that whatever view is found with `itemId` will be a `BottomNavigationItemView`. But here's where you're calling that function:

```
BottomNavigationHelper().showBadge(this, databinding.bottomNavView, R.id.bottom_nav_view)
```

The ID you're passing is `bottom_nav_view`, and the View in your XML with that ID is a `BottomNavigationView`, **not** a `BottomNavigationItemView`. And that's what your error is explaining:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView cannot be cast
    to com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView
        at com.abc.project.views.BottomNavigationHelper.showBadge(HomeActivity.kt:128)
```

---

As far as fixing it goes, I don't know what a `BottomNavigationItemView` is supposed to be, it's not part of the Material library. You could ask the person who posted the answer you're working from by adding a comment?

The approach they're going for is basically

- add items to the navigation bar with unique IDs
- inside the `BottomNavigationView` (which is a `FrameLayout`), find the `View` with a particular ID
- add your badge `View` to that found `View` (which implies that what you found is actually a `ViewGroup` since that's what has an `addView` method)

Offhand I don't know how `BottomNavigationView`s work internally, if the items they create from your menu actually are `ViewGroup`s, etc. So I don't know if this approach will actually work, I'm just giving you a line of investigation really.

---

That said, the Material Design library allows you to add badges to your bottom navigation items natively ([scroll down to *Adding badges*](https://m2.material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android)). This lets you add a [BadgeDrawable](https://m2.material.io/develop/android/components/badging) which may or may not be customisable to what you want. I'd look into the stuff like that which is provided, before you start trying to manipulate the view hierarchy directly

Comment: Appreciate the effort you took to answer my query. I Implemented the same using a GitHub library. Thank you. 

https://github.com/Droppers/AnimatedBottomBar